# Vim: Skip quickfix buffer when cycling through windows

Tags: vim

A common pattern when I edit files in vim is to have two buffers open using `:sb`, and cycle between them using `C-w C-w`. I tend to avoid having more two windows open because then the cognitive (and number of keystrokes) overhead of switching becomes higher.

I recently started using the quickfix functionality provided by `:make`, and now I have a dilemma. You see, the quickfix window constitutes another window: so now if I am mashing `C-w C-w` I have to cycle through three buffers, one of which I don't actually want to cycle into (usually). So, is there a way to make the buffer cycling commands skip `qf` windows?

General suggestions on how to improve my vim workflow here would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override the command with a custom mapping in which you check for the quickfix window, and then just jump again:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <C-w><C-w> <C-w><C-w>:if &buftype ==# 'quickfix'<Bar>wincmd w<Bar>endif<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do also is make a `<c-w>l` and `<c-w>h` and `<c-w>k` and `<c-w>j` to switch to the window in that direction